# Post messages from Facebook App to users who like it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api

How to post messages from my Facebook App to users (exact users or all) who signed (likes) my App?

Comment: You mean through ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is Koala gem which satisfy your needs and you can also verify the Facebook Graph API.

[Koala Gem Github](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/)

Read the graph API wiki in koala gem. Here you will find how to write a post in users wall. For getting FB App users list you have to read FB graph API documentation.

P.S: Read the koala gem wiki completely.